# How to use PKI (public/private key) encryption in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, ssl, encryption, cryptography, pki

I want to encrypt a string such that the end user can verify it was encrypted by me, but such that they can't encrypt it themselves.

For example, I have a private key 'private', a public key 'public', a message 'hello world' and want to do something like:

```
private_key = 'private'
public_key = 'public'
message = 'hello world'

encrypted_value = Crypto.encrypt(message, private_key)
# encrypted_value is now 'd92a01df241a3'

is_verified = Crypto.verify(message, public_key)
# given just the public key and the message, is_verified will 
# be able to tell whether it's accurate

# note that the encrypted_value cannot be generated by just the public_key
# but it can be verified by the public_key
```

Comment: You probably meant `is_verified = Crypto.verify(encrypted_value, public_key)`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are looking for built-in [Ruby OpenSSL wrapper](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL.html). The documentation provides examples of how to do it.

NOTE: Using `.sign` method below to sign your data with a private key only generates a digital signature, it does not encrypt your data. From your question, it is not clear if you want to encrypt your data or just validate the message. If you want to encrypt the data, you will also have to use [`Cipher`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/Cipher.html) class. You need only a digital signature to verify that your data has not been tempered with and been signed by you!

#### Sign your message

```
require 'openssl'

# Load PRIVATE key
private_key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(File.read('private_key.pem'))

# Sign your data
signature = private_key.sign(OpenSSL::Digest::SHA256.new, message)

# Our message signature that ensures that our data is signed by our private key
puts signature    # => "\x04\xEC\xCC?\xDE\x8F\x91>G\xC2*M\xA7j\xA5\x16\..."
```

Now, send your data & signature to the receiving end. Also, you may consider using [PKCS#7](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/PKCS7.html) as a standard way to pack your data and signature.

#### Verify your message & signature

```
require 'openssl'

# Load PUBLIC key
public_key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(File.read('public_key.pem'))

# We have received the following data
message = "Hello World!"
signature = "\x04\xEC\xCC?\xDE\x8F\x91>G\..."    # Long signature

# Verify the message & its signature
if public_key.verify(OpenSSL::Digest::SHA256.new, signature, message)
    "VALID: Signed by pair private key"
else
    "NOT VALID: Data tampered or private-public key mismatch!"
end
```

Comment: can you give example  with encode & sign ?